# numpy meshgrid of dynamic shape

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use numpy meshgrid to generate some arrays. So, I have a nd array. Let us call it data and it can have an arbitrary shape and I am trying to generate some indices array as follows:

```
shape = data.shape

x = np.meshgrid[1,x-1 for x in shape]
```

I know the syntax looks crazy but sometimes I try things like these in python and it works! Anyway, is there a way to do this dynamic meshgrid in python? This comes back with invalid syntax error:

```
 x = np.meshgrid[1,x-1 for x in shape]
                        ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

EDIT:

I would like basically to create an array of indices. For example, I can do the following when the index always begins with 0

```
import numpy as np

array = np.random.rand(5, 5, 5)
shape = array.shape
indices = np.indices(x-1 for x in shape)
```

This creates an ndarray with indices starting from 0 to (n-1) along each of the axes of my input array. Now, I wanted to have the indexing begin from 1 and could not find a good way to do this.

EDIT:

For example, a call for an array with shape (4, 5, 6) could be something like:

```
 x = np.meshgrid(np.arange(1,4), np.arange(1,5), np.arange(1, 6))
```

Comment: Post an example of what you hope to get.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you intend that to result in something like `np.meshgrid(1, a-1, b-1, c-1)` for a shape `(a, b, c)`?  Why are you using brackets instead of parentheses?

Comment: I edited the question. Hopefully this makes it more clear

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show an explicit version of the `meshgrid` call you want, given a sample shape?  For instance, if the shape is `(4, 5, 6)`, what exactly do you intend the `meshgrid` call to be?

Comment: Hi BrenBarn, sorry I had misunderstood. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Going off your last example, you can do something like this:

```
x = np.meshgrid(*[np.arange(1, x) for x in shape])
```

You need to explicitly create a list of the values you want to pass to `meshgrid`.  If you want each one to start at 1, you need to put the 1 in each call to `arange`.  You can't do something like `[1, arange(x)]` and have it "distribute" the 1 through all the calls.

Then the `*` there expands the list into separate arguments.  (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters) for info.)

Comment: Wow, incredible! Thanks so much. Had no idea about this *[ syntax. What is it?!

Comment: The `[` is just part of a normal list comprehension.  I added a link to an explanation of the `*`.  What it does is it unpacks the list one by one into function arguments.  So if you have a list `blah = [1, 2, 3}`, doing `f(*blah)` is like doing `f(1, 2, 3)`, with each list element passed as a separate argument.

Comment: this seems to be extremely slow for very large x, or am I wrong?